# NextGEN Gallery - Permalink Issue - urlencode Hebrew

Tags: wordpress, arabic, urlencode, hebrew, nextgen-gallery

In file `products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_imagebrowser/package.module.nextgen_basic_imagebrowser.php`, on line `74` you have a check to find the current image.

The relevant code is:

`if ($picture->image_slug == $pid)`

The thing is that `$pid` is a *clean* string, and `$picture->image_slug` is *URL-encoded*.
For example, `$pid` is `מיראז-1` while `$picture->image_slug` is `%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%96-1`.

If you upload **an image with a filename in Hebrew/Arabic** - the result is that you always only see the first image in the imagebrowser.
The plugin can't show any other image, besides the first. Both with or without AJAX.

I went through [all of the filters and actions](http://hookr.io/plugins/nextgen-gallery-by-photocrati/) possible with the plugin,
but it only affects the logic after this part that I was referring to.

Any thoughts on this?